# Regex: match multiple times between tags

Tags: regex

I have following string:

```
def index.html index.html default <span class='fp-default'>#default</span> def <span class='fp-default'>#default ddsad def</span>#default<span class='fp-user' default>#user</span>#default
```

And I want to match all occurrences of given substring (e.g. `def`) that is between tags.

So far I managed to create following regexp, but it didn't work properly (matches only one occurrence between tags):

```
(?:(?<=>)|^)([^<]*?(def)[^<]*?)*(?:(?=<)|$)
```

Online regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/oc3ptR/6

Any ideas? Tx!

Comment: Consider using a parser instead of regex. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
def(?=[^<>]*?<\/)
```

Explanation:

1. `def` matches `def`
2. `(?=[^<>]*<\/)` Positive look ahead that is looking for a `</` i.e.
   end tag without matching `<` and `>` before it `[^<>]*?`

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/ID8W5y/1/)